# Flask Python Google OAuth - Client Id not found

Tags: python, flask, oauth

I'm trying to implement Google OAuth2 into my webapp, using the demo source code provided by Google: https://github.com/authlib/demo-oauth-client/tree/master/flask-google-login , but I'm getting "Authorisation Error Error 401: invalid_client The OAuth client was not found".

In the URL queryString I can also see `&client_id=None`.

It looks like the demo code is out of date.

I've tried recreating client ids and secrets to no avail.

Can someone help me present the valid Google login screen?

Below are the files.

`config.py` - in the same directory as `app.py` :

```
import os

GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = os.getenv('<client id>')
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv('<client secret>')
```

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, session
from flask import render_template, redirect
from authlib.integrations.flask_client import OAuth

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = '!secret'
app.config.from_object('config')

CONF_URL = 'https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration'
oauth = OAuth(app)
oauth.register(
    name='google',
    server_metadata_url=CONF_URL,
    client_kwargs={
        'scope': 'openid email profile'
    }
)


@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    user = session.get('user')
    return render_template('home.html', user=user)


@app.route('/login')
def login():
    redirect_uri = url_for('auth', _external=True)
    return oauth.google.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri)


@app.route('/auth')
def auth():
    token = oauth.google.authorize_access_token()
    session['user'] = token['userinfo']
    return redirect('/')


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('user', None)
    return redirect('/')
```

PIP list

- Authlib==1.1.0
- Flask==2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by doing the following:

- Removing the trailing '/' from the Authorised redirect URIs in Google Console, Credentials section.
- Added `client_id = app.config['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID']` to `oauth.register`